# ANTLR4: parse number as identifier instead as numeric literal

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have this situation, of having to treat integer as identifier.
Underlying language syntax (unfortunately) allows this.

grammar excerpt:

```
grammar Alang;

...

NLITERAL   : [0-9]+ ;
...
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
```

Example code, that has to be dealt with:

```
/** declaration block **/

Method 465;
...
```

In above code example, because `NLITERAL` has to be placed before `IDENTIFIER`, parser picks `465` as `NLITERAL`.

What is a good way to deal with such a situations?
(Ideally, avoiding application code within grammar, to keep it runtime agnostic)

I found similar questions on SO, not exactly helpful though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to make `465` produce either an `NLITERAL` token or an `IDENTIFIER` token depending on context (you might be able to use lexer modes, but that's probably not a good fit for your needs).

What you can do rather easily though, is to allow `NLITERAL`s in addition to `IDENTIFIERS` in certain places. So you could define a parser rule

```
methodName: IDENTIFIER | NLITERAL;
```

and then use that rule instead of `IDENTIFIER` where appropriate.

Comment: with this, I will violate semantics of syntax, but it does seem there's no better option than this.  things you have to do, to compensate for bad coding practices and lang design which permits it. It would be good if ANTLR supports handling such cases OOTB in grammar, while being runtime agnostic.